# No Sound on my Toshiba Satellite L455D-S5976

Tags: sound, toshiba-satellite

No Sound on my Toshiba Satellite L455D-S5976,  Running Ubuntu 11.10  32Bit,  ATI,  IXP AC97, Realtek ALC250 rev.2

Turned the volume up on all volume settings. Turned up the volume in the aslamixer, and still no sound. Searched on-line with little help found.

Computer had sound before loading Ubuntu 11.10 32Bit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the headphones? Also, I have something like this going on with my Sony VPCZ114GX, there is a workaround posted for my model at this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/960124 Basically involves loading up David Henninsson's hda-jack-retask from his ppa at https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda and then try Wouter van der Graaf's workaround on comment #7.

As for getting the model of your sound card, I tried the below. Although the problem may be that your machine doesn't know what model to use for sound in the first place.

Found with: $ aplay -l ** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ** card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog] ...

Then to get the model to put in alsa-base.conf: $ gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz |grep -i "alc889" intel-alc889a Intel IbexPeak with ALC889A intel-x58 Intel DX58 with ALC889